# XML implementations with EJBs

Tags: java, xml, ejb

I would like to know please what kind of XML implementations provide EJBs ? Is there Saxbuilder or other implementations ?

Thank you

Comment: I find this question quite unclear. Can you explain a bit more what you want to do?

Comment: I just want to know if I have to import jar file of SAX or DOM to use it with EJBs please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SAX and DOM implementations are part of the standard Java runtime libraries. You don't have to import anything to use them.

Note that this is not related to EJBs. You can use SAX and DOM in any Java application